# How to dynamic import in nextjs correctly?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to use nextjs `dynamic` import. I am using nextjs `"^12.3.0"` and typescript with module path aliases.

Here is `HomeIcon` component.

```js
export const HomeIcon: FunctionComponent<IconProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      fill="none"
      onClick={onClick}
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      strokeWidth={1.5}
      stroke="currentColor"
      className="w-6 h-6"
    >
      <path
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        d="M2.25 12l8.954-8.955c.44-.439 1.152-.439 1.591 0L21.75 12M4.5 9.75v10.125c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125H9.75v-4.875c0-.621.504-1.125 1.125-1.125h2.25c.621 0 1.125.504 1.125 1.125V21h4.125c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V9.75M8.25 21h8.25"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

So, my component imports looks like so..

```js
import { HomeIcon } from '@/components/Icons/HomeIcon';
```

Usage:

```js
<HomeIcon />
```

With Nextjs I am trying to import dynamically

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const DynamicHomeIcon =dynamic(() =>  import '@/components/Icons/HomeIcon');
```

Usage:

```
<DynamicHomeIcon />
```

I get the following error with TS.
How do I fix that?

[image: error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a named export like your case, you need to return it from the Promise.
So your dynamic import should look like this:

```js
const DynamicHomeIcon = dynamic(() =>  import ('@/components/Icons/HomeIcon').then(mod => mod.HomeIcon));
```

For a reference, its mentioned here in the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-named-exports)